# Reclaim transaction hash

Tags: seed, wallet, address, iota-recovery

I have just reviewed the transaction hash of the reclaim tool's process and cannot identify the address that this hash references? I understand that it should be the address at index zero for the new seed. However, after having already attached the first address it is apparent that they are not the same.

Comment: The address of the proof transaction of the recovery process is *not* the first address of the new seed, [but a hash of it](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/247416c07c351fe59879a3fe19d84ce90ebeead3/ui/js/ui.recover.js#L433-L468);
and the Reveal transaction [reuses the address of the Proof transaction](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/247416c07c351fe59879a3fe19d84ce90ebeead3/ui/js/ui.recover.js#L278)

Comment: Which hash are you referring to?

Comment: All three point to the same address (if I remember correctly). However,  this question was answered and aparently the address referenced to isn't the first address of the new seed.

Comment: Is there any way to verify the deposit address for the new seed?